# Xgboost algorithm with entry point file issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-glue, xgboost, xgbregressor

I am trying to create aws glue spark job to train one of the data set . I am using xgboost algorithm in 1.3-1 version . When i try to run the estimator , i am having issue

infrastructure : aws glue 4.00 spark shell

all file folders are s3 path

code snippet.

```
xgb_script_mode_estimator = XGBoost(
    entry_point="training.py",
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
    role=role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type=instance_type,
    framework_version="1.3-1",
    output_path="s3://{}/{}/{}/output".format(hyperparameters['bucket_nm'], '/output/', job_name),
```

error :

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'training.py'

I placed the "glue script" and training.py in the same job bucket in same folder with **init**.py file .

The XGBoost function is not recognizing the training.py in the same folder (no name mismatch for the training file including case)

Comment: Check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/how-it-works-engines.html#how-it-works-ray

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved by adding  "Source-dir" parameter in the XGBboost function by pointing to trianing.py file location